# Custom IPasswordHasher not being used

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So I'm trying to use a custom IPasswordHasher implementation but for whatever reason it just never seems to be called, I've got breakpoints on it but it's just never going into them at all.

My password hasher looks like:

```cs
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace ViamondeMobile
{
    public class PasswordHasherMembership : IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>
    {
        IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser> _identityPasswordHasher = new PasswordHasher<IdentityUser>();

        internal static string HashPasswordInOldFormat(string password)
        {
            var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(password);
            var sha1data = sha1.ComputeHash(data);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(sha1data);
        }

        //the password of the new users will be hashed with the new algorithm
        public string HashPassword(IdentityUser user, string password)
        {
            return _identityPasswordHasher.HashPassword(user, password);
        }

        public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(IdentityUser user, string hashedPassword,
                                                               string providedPassword)
        {
            string pwdHash2 = HashPasswordInOldFormat(providedPassword);

            if (hashedPassword == pwdHash2)
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                return _identityPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, providedPassword);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Startup.cs ConfigureServices is looking like:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(o =>
                {
                    o.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
                }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddDbContext<ViamondemyviamondecomContext>(options =>

                options.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Viamonde"))
            );

            services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<IdentityUser>, PasswordHasherMembership>();

            services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ViamondemyviamondecomContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"; });
        }
```

But for the life of me I can't figure out why the custom hasher isn't being used, hoping I'm missing something obvious and someone comes in and makes me feel silly haha!

Edit:

The controller I'm using for testing is this: (Not the most scientific in the world, I just want to see it working before I move forwards)

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TripsController : ControllerBase
    {

        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        public ViamondemyviamondecomContext db = new ViamondemyviamondecomContext();

        public TripsController(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestRegister()
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser
                       {
                           UserName = "mike",
                           Email = "ob@fuscat.ed"
                       };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "9S5e2rQ8lKsy1595Y5^Ww#");

            return LocalRedirect("/");
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("[action]")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> TestLogin()
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("mike", "9S5e2rQ8lKsy1595Y5^Ww#", true, false);


            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return LocalRedirect("/");
            }
            else
            {
                return LocalRedirect("/");
            }
        }
```

I'm just calling the TestRegister and TestLogin functions and then seeing if my breakpoints on my Hasher are hit or not, so far they haven't been at all.

EDIT: I see this has been marked as a duplicate despite me replying to say that the question linked didn't really help me so I thought I'd put it here just in case this actually gets read instead you never know your luck I guess.

Basically the question I keep getting linked doesn't help seeing as all the context is now gone, it's very hard to piece together what the answer given is supposed to be for my particular case with 0 context hence me asking again. I came across that question before asking here and it was little help to me then either.

Comment: You are registering IPasswordHasher, but I can't see where you are telling MVC to actually use it.

Comment: I've looked at that link countless times however with the original project link now dead there's not much context to go on. I mean I have no idea what the AppUser mentioned in the top answer is for example so I'm not sure what to do based on that.

Comment: I don't see a problem with the code you've shown. How are you testing this?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I've added the way I'm testing above, I'm tearing my hair out over this, started a new project to see if I could get it working there and it just did..... with exactly what I've put here which is super frustrating!